# PHP header() doesn't load CSS on next .php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form that validates a log in page and then executes

```
header("Location: http://....../main.php/");
```

when it redirects, the CSS will not load in the main.php

[image: Error given by the console]

but when I manually visit the page, the CSS is applied and no error is reported.

The page is generated by PHP echo statements with HTML tags.

Adding the CSS:

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Please show me the section of the header when the main css included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `/` from after `main.php`

```
header("Location: http://....../main.php");
```

Comment: The /CSS/main.css made it confused

Comment: Confused? :) I just tried find out your file path, but you know :) The main problem is, if you don't use / before include a file, the path with bee relative from current url

Comment: So should edit my answer? I will delete the CSS part, and you can accept my answer if your problem have solved

Comment: Sounds good. I know the CSS starts from the root that way, but I'm running it from a school server for my school project and it has a home directory for each student and it simply doesn't find it.